# Sets of irrationals whose square contains a rational

Tags: discrete-mathematics, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Let $S$ be a subset of the irrationals. Also, lets assume that $S$ has infinitely many elements. My very general question is, under what *non-trivial* conditions does there exist an element $x\in S$ such that $x^2$ is rational. For example, if $S$ were the entire set of irrationals, then the usual proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational would find such an $x$. On the other hand, the same methods would not necessarily be sufficient if $S$ is a strict subset of the irrationals. Is there some natural set of actions we can throw into $S$ to find such an $x$? For example, we could assume $S$ is closed under addition and multiplication. Is there some general theory about any of this?

I would appreciate examples of such non-trivial sets $S$.

Comment: Closed under addition and multiplication is not enough, as seen from $S=\{\,\sum_{n=1}^N a_n\pi^n\mid N\in\mathbb N, a_n\in\mathbb N_0, \sum_{n=1}^N a_n>0\,\}$. All elements of these $S$ (and their squares) are transcendental.

Comment: If $S$ consists of all the irrationals in an open interval (in the usual topology on the reals), then $S$ contains (infinitely many) square roots of rationals. [But I'm not sure I can defend against an accusation of triviality]

Answer (score 0):

The exact condition is that $S$ intersects $\{\pm\sqrt{r}: 0 \le r \in {\mathbb Q}\}$,
where $\mathbb Q$ is the rationals.  It's a dense set, but countable, and therefore very "easy to miss" by anything that doesn't have to contain an open interval.

Comment: I understand what I'm asking for is quite general but, this doesn't really answer anything. Obviously if I knew the intersection is non-trivial then I'd be done. I'm interested if there are some non-trivial relations that define $S$ from which one could deduce that there is a rational upon squaring.

Comment: You're right, Alex, it doesn't answer anything, but I suspect it's the best answer you're going to get.